# All possible options to call R from .Net(C#) in parallel

Tags: c#, r, r.net

Hi i am working on a framework, which need to call the execution of R in parallel. Is there any options? I tried it with R.Net but i cant use it to execute R-Scripts in parallel. And it seems to be buggy.

Thx in advance.

Comment: There are several ways to call R in parallel. I think you should be more specific about your problem to give people some idea.

Comment: Thx for your fast answer. Sorry for my bad english. What i want is just to execute 2 and more R scripts in different workflows in parallel. Its like i have 4 R-Editors in my C# program and when i hit "GO" button then all the scripts should be executed independently but not after each other.